# Adding paths to a Google Maps (API v3)

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, maps

I'm trying to use the Google Maps API v3 to display a map on my website. I want it to display some bus lines of my city. It should look like a colored path (e.g. a red path for line 1) which displays the trip the bus makes.

This is what I have till now: http://dejoridavid.pe.hu/sasabus/map.php. On the map the markers display the locations of the busses, only the line paths are missing. How can I add a path to my map using the Google Maps API v3? It shall be a path going from A to B to C and so on, then reaching A again.

Comment: Sounds like you want to use the [Directions service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions). Alternatively you may want to draw lots of [polylines](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#polylines)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from the [Google Maps API docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polyline-simple) (I added comments to clarify what is happening)

```
// initialize a mapOptions object
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 3,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, -180),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
};

// initialize a map object
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

// initialize an array of LatLng objects. These are your markers in your city
var flightPlanCoordinates = [
        new google.maps.LatLng(37.772323, -122.214897),
        new google.maps.LatLng(21.291982, -157.821856),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-18.142599, 178.431),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-27.46758, 153.027892)];

// initialize a Polyline object. You can set the color, width, opacity, etc. 
var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
});

// set the polyline's map with your map object from above.
flightPath.setMap(map);
```